# Can python-pptx module insert video?

Tags: python, video, powerpoint

according to the [documentation](http://python-pptx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/placeholders-understanding.html), python-pptx can insert videos, however, the documentation does not give very good examples. Anybody have any code snippets to add **video1.avi** to my pptx?

```
from pptx import Presentation
pptx1 = Presentation()
slide = pptx1.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_layout)
```

not sure what inputs I need

```
slide.placeholders.element.add_placeholder(id_,name,ph_type, orient, sz,idx)
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:** `python-pptx` now supports inserting videos (and probably audio in many cases using the same method).

---

<s>I'm not sure where in the documentation it says it can insert videos, but if you can cite a particular location I'll fix it.</s>

<s>We've looked at this feature, but it turns out to be quite complex as different video formats require a substantial amount of undocumented customization to the metadata inserted into the XML surrounding the embedded video object. Also as I recall one needs a way to get a still image (first frame maybe) from the video to insert in it's place while it's not running, and libraries for this sort of thing are not readily available in Python last time we looked.</s>

Anyway, the short answer is no, it's not supported yet. And it's not likely to come soon unless there's a motivated contributor or sponsor. Sorry I didn't have happier news for you :(

Comment: The media clip placeholder( see the link from the original post) sounded like what I needed. I appreciate your feedback, regardless of outcome. Would a gif animation work?

Comment: Ah, right, so those can be present in a .pptx file and python-pptx will happily leave them alone and preserve them on save. There's no mechanism for inserting them yet; they can only be present on a slide layout and there hasn't been any demand so far for programmatically creating layouts. But even if one is present, it only allows a video to be inserted at runtime via the UI. Sorry I didn't click the link, I just assumed from the link name it was the documentation home page :)

Answer (score 5):

The library now has a function for adding videos to slides:

```
slide.shapes.add_movie(video_file, x_pos, y_pos, width, height, poster_frame_image=thumbnail_image_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up converting my avi video to an animated gif, and that successfully inserted into the pptx

```py
aviname = 'vid1.avi'
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
aviname = 'vid1.avi'
clip = VideoFileClip(aviname)
clip.write_gif(os.path.splitext(aviname)[0]+'.gif')
```

Comment: Are you able to play the animated gif after inserting it or does the animated gif behave like a picture(no motion)?

Comment: The animated gif plays the animati on depending on how the gif was created, ie, if it was created to loop or play once. You can experiment by manually inserting a gif into a presentation and activating presentation mode.

Answer (score 1):

this video could help you:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5a1kH996DJM&t=315s
he speaks arabic. Here is the code:

import pptx
from pptx.utils import Cm
from pptx.enum.shapes import PP_MEDIA_TYPE

pres = pptx.Presentation()

blank_slide = pres.slides.add_slide(pres.slide_layouts[6])
movie_path = "path"

movie_shape = blank_slide.shapes.add_movie(left = Cm(5), top = Cm(5), width = Cm(10), height = Cm(10), poster_frame_image = "image_path", mime_type = "video/mp4")

movie_shape.media_type = PP_MEDIA_TYPE.MOVIE

pres.save("pres.pptx")

Comment: Please include the code, otherwise this should be a comment, not an answer.